# Connected optimization problems

Tags: bilevel-optimization, multi-stage

I'm working on a set of interconnected problems and I'm not sure how I can solve across the connection. First, a set of variables, $x$, is solved using the following:
$$\max_{x}f(x)$$
Subject to:
$$w^Tx \geq d$$

Assuming that the objective is finite, the solution is then input to a second problem:
$$\min_{w,d}g(x)$$
Subject to:
$$w \geq 0$$
$$d \geq 0$$

In other words $x$ is selected solely to maximize $f(x)$, essentially in a completely separate process, but the choice of $w$ and $d$ affect what $x$ is selected which affects the final minimization problem. The overall objective is the minimization problem.

It doesn't seem there's a way to combine these problems. I'm considering an alternating solution where $f(x)$ is maximized for fixed $w$ and $d$, then $g(x)$ is evaluated. The knowledge of $g(x)$ informs how I update $w$ and $d$, however it's not clear to me how to update $w$ and $d$ as I can't just differentiate a function with respect to $w$ and $d$. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the OP correctly, this is an example of a [bi-level optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilevel_optimization) problem.

It can be formulated as follows:
\begin{align}
    \min_{w, d} \quad & g(x)\\
    \text{s.t.} \quad & w \geq 0\\
    & d \geq 0\\
    & \begin{array}{rl}
        \displaystyle x \in \arg \max_{x} & f(x) \\
        \text{s.t.} & w^{T}x \geq d
    \end{array}
\end{align}
where the outer minimization is referred to as the \emph{upper-level} (or leader) and the inner maximization as the \emph{lower-level} (or follower) problem.
Note that, when solving the lower level problem, $w$ and $d$ are fixed.

In other words: the leader chooses $w$ and $d$ so as to minimize $g(x)$, where $x$ is chosen by the follower so as to maximize $f(x)$ given $w, d$ chosen by the leader.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. It seems like my intuition was correct; this is not simple to solve. Seems like I may need to use a genetic algorithm to approximate a solution. Thanks!

Comment: The difficulty of solving the bi-level problem comes (mostly) from the nature of the follower's problem. In your case, the nature of the objective functions $f$ and $g$ (linear? convex? non-convex?) will play a big role. A typical approach (when the lower problem is linear / quadratic) is to use a single-level reformulation (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilevel_optimization#KKT_reformulation)

Comment: That is something that I had thought of before I made this post actually. $x$ is discrete so I don't believe the KKT reformulation applies. Thank you so much for the help. I will do some research on python packages/implementations of genetic/evolutionary algorithms to see if I can get to a "good enough" solution